# Buttons in the first column disappear when sorting the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable that shows mock json data retrieved from a text file. I have removed the first column as it contains the id and it isn't ideal to display the id on the table. I appended a buy button on each row on the first column only. However, when I sort the table the button disappears and the original first column data also appears.

[image: Ideal]
[image: Problem]

JavScript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON('/apps/mchp/clientlibs/clientlib-site/components/parametrictable/data.txt', function(json) {


    var data = json.data;
    var $thead = $('#parametrictable').find('thead');
    var tr = $("<tr>");
    $thead.append(tr);
    var columns = [];
    var obj = Object.keys(data[0]);
    console.log(data[0])
    var button = '<div class="left-btn"><i class="download fas fa-file-download"></i></div><div class="right-btn"><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-area"><input type="text" value="100"></div><div class="input-group-icon">BUY</div></div></div>';


    $.each(data[0], function(name, value) {
      var column = {
        "data": name,
        "title":name
      };
    $('tr').find('th:first-child',).remove();

      columns.push(column);

    });

    for (i=1; i<obj.length; i++) {
        $(".dropdown-content").append('<li><input type="checkbox" class="dropcheck" data-column="'+i+'"/>'+obj[i]+'</li>');
    }   

    var table= $('#tableId').DataTable({
      data: data,
      columns: columns,
        columnDefs: [ {
            orderable: true,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   1
        } ],
        select: {
            style:    'multi',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    });

    $('tr').find('th:first-child').remove();
    $('tr').find('td:first-child').remove();
    $('tr').find('td:first-child').append(button);


  $('tr').on('change', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('change!');
  });

  $('input[type=checkbox]').on( 'change', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var column = table.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );
    column.visible( ! column.visible() );
    } );

  $('.show-all').on( 'click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    var obj = Object.keys(data[0])
    for (i=1; i<obj.length; i++) {
        var col = table.columns([i]);
        if (col.visible().join(', ') == 'false') {
            col.visible(true);
             $(".dropcheck").prop("checked", false);
        }
    }
    } ); 

   });
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is not a good practice to hide datatable columns by .remove(), datatables have a built-in code for that by columnDefs refer: 
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html

Second, that is not the right way to append data/html in datatable columns, use rowCallback function for datatable, see:

```
            columnDefs: [
                 {
                   "targets": [ 0 ],
                   "visible": false,
                   "searchable": false
                },
            ],
            rowCallback: function(row, data, index) {

                if($('td:eq(1)', row).find('.download').length == 0)
                {
                    $('td:eq(1)', row).append(button);
                }
            },
```

When using datatable sort or search or any datatable actions it always refreshes the table therefore, any initialization before the action will be disregarded unless executed again.

Comment: hey thanks! this worked however when i sorted the table again, it kept appending the button to each row. how do i stop it from adding more than one button?

Comment: oh i see, just check if button exist in the row before append:

                    if($('td:eq(1)', row).find('.download').length == 0)
                    {
                        $('td:eq(1)', row).append(button);
                    }